# Draw a Directed Acyclic Graph from a makefile

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis

I am completely new to Analysis of Algorithms and I have to draw a Directed Acyclic Graph from the makefile below. (I know what a DAG is).
My question is simple: should I do it just by watching the makefile or is there an algorithm I can use? All I want is to be oriented so I have a way to start.

An additional question about this problem is:
How many valid orderings exist for processing the makefile? I will very much appreciate your feedback for this second question.

```
project: main.o utils.o command.o
    cc -o project main.o utils.o command.o
main.o: main.c defs.h
    cc -c main.c
utils.o: utils.c defs.h command.h
    cc -cutils.c
command.o: command.c defs.h command.h
    cc -c command . c
```

Comment: Is the problem that you do not know how the Makefile works or that you do not know what a DAG is (or something else)?

Comment: I know how a make file works (more or less) and I also know what a DAG is. My issue is how to attack the design of the graph.

Comment: What I would guess, although the description isn't very clear, is that you have to make a dependency graph. For example, `project` depends on `main.o`, `utils.o` and `command.o`. These have further dependencies, etc.

Comment: That is correct, it is about a dependency graph in the form of a DAG. If I do it just by watching the makefile, it is a correct approach?

Comment: If you know all the things, I don't understand what your question is. We won't just solve your exercise for you. Community votes, please: unclear?

Comment: My issue is that if it is a correct approach to draw the DAG only from watching the makefile or if there is an algorithm I should follow. I am not asking to solve my problem in any way. You can see my goal if you pay close attention to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not entirely clear from the exercise, it looks like you should make a dependency graph. A dependency graph has *nodes* for the *objects* that can depend on each other, and an edge from $x$ to $y$ when $x$ depends on $y$ (or the other way around, depending on the definition).

In a Makefile, the objects are the targets and files. Dependencies can be directly read from the Makefile in the target lines: the targets depend on that what comes after the colon.